# How do I construct a fix-sized matrix from an array of numbers in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an array of numbers

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

How do I construct a 3x3 matrix where the first row contains 1,2,3; the second row contains 4,5,6; the third row contains 7, 8, 9?

Essentially, I want to fill the numbers into the 3x3 matrix row by row.

In R, I can construct this matrix using this command:

> matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)

How do I accomplish this in Java?

Comment: Is the array already initialized with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial the array :

```
 int [][] numbers = new int [nrow][ncol]; // suppose 3X3
```

Assign each index to some *integer* number:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
 for(int i = 0 ; i < nrow ; i++)
  for(int j = 0 ; j < ncol; j++)
    numbers[i][j] = s.nextInt();
```

And print the matrix :

```
for(int []n : numbers){
  for(int i : n){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
 System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int arr[][] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
```